# pdftk under Tomcat - permissions for generated report file

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, tomcat, pdftk

I have a server with Ubuntu 12.04 and I have a Servlet under tomcat that is used to split PDF files. When the file is uploaded to the Servlet, It opens an external process (using [commons-exec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/)) and calls PDFTK and uses the "burst" option to split the uploaded PDF file.

The problem is that PDFTK also generates a file doc_data.txt which is defined according to the man page as "the same as the output from dump_data". [pdftk man page](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/)

The external process is terminating with error. When I checked various logs, it tries to write the doc_data.txt file is in the /proc/2400/cwd/ and fails because it does not have permissions (found that in catalina logs). The 2400 in the path above seems to be the process id for Tomcat and is changing when I restart the Tomcat server.

what permissions should I give? and how to give when the dir is changing?
I don't have full understanding regarding /proc and I do not want to mess up things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cwd` means current working directory and `proc` is a virtual filesystem (doesn't write data to the disk).

First, find out what that points to: `readlink -e /proc/<pid>/cwd/`
Then check the permissions of that directory using `ls -l`.
You can now check if the spawned process may write into that directory and take appropriate action.